# Wordpress - jetpack infinite scroll not working

Tags: wordpress

So I've added them support for infinite scroll in my functions.php like so

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'  => 'content',
    'footer'     => 'page',
     'posts_per_page'    => 4
) );
```

Here's my template and loop, I added an arbitrary div with the id of 'content' just because jetpack apparently needs the containing div of your posts to be an ID, yet the infinite scroll still doesn't work.

```
<?php 


/*
    Template Name: News
*/

?>


<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="main-content">



    <div class="content-left">
    <div id="content">

        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts('posts_per_page=&paged=' . $paged); 
        ?>


        <?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('clearfix') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">





            <div class="entrywrapper">

                <div class="entry">




                <div class="bordertop">
                 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                </div> <!-- end div bordertop -->

                <div class="aligncenter grey">  
                <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                </div>
                    <div class="meta">


                <span>Posted in :<?php the_category($separator = ' / '); ?></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div> <!-- end div meta -->


                <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
                <div class="figure">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div> <!-- end div figure //centers thumbnail -->


                      <p class="firstparaph"> <?php the_field('main_post_meta'); ?></p>

                        <?php the_content('Continue Reading >'); ?>
                        <div class="centerm">
                         <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comments-link', ''); ?>
                        </div>              
                    <div class="postbreaker">* * *</div> <!-- end div entrybreaker -->
                </div> <!-- end div entry -->








            <div style="clear:both"></div>


            </div> <!-- end div entrywrapper -->

            <div style="clear:both"></div>

            </div> <!-- end div post -->




    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
            <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end div ID content -->
    </div> <!-- end div content-left -->

    <div class="content-right">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div> <!-- end div content-right -->


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> <!-- end div main-content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

In functions.php

```
function get_post_content() {
?>
    <div <?php post_class('clearfix') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entrywrapper">
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="bordertop">
                 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                </div> <!-- end div bordertop -->
                <div class="aligncenter grey">  
                <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="meta">
                <span>Posted in :<?php the_category($separator = ' / '); ?></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div> <!-- end div meta -->
                <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
                <div class="figure">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div> <!-- end div figure //centers thumbnail -->
                <p class="firstparaph"> <?php the_field('main_post_meta'); ?></p>
                <?php the_content('Continue Reading >'); ?>
                <div class="centerm">
                    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comments-link', ''); ?>
                </div>              
                <div class="postbreaker">* * *</div> <!-- end div entrybreaker -->
                </div> <!-- end div entry -->
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div> <!-- end div entrywrapper -->

            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div> <!-- end div post -->
<?php
}
```

Then in your blog loop file:

```
<?php 


/*
    Template Name: News
*/

?>


<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="main-content">



    <div class="content-left">
    <div id="content">

        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts('posts_per_page=&paged=' . $paged); 
        ?>


        <?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

           <!-- MY EDIT IS HERE -->
           get_post_content();

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
            <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end div ID content -->
    </div> <!-- end div content-left -->

    <div class="content-right">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div> <!-- end div content-right -->


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> <!-- end div main-content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```